# Create brand new weapon with BlockBench and a MineCraft Plugin API

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I would like to use Blockbench (a 3d modelling application like blender) to create an entirely new Minecraft weapon.

Then, with java and some API (for example bukkit), I want to have a brand-new weapon.

I do not want to retexture an existing weapon for example the diamond sword.

Would someone kindly give me some pointers? For example, what is not clear for me is how to export it from Blockbench, and how to import it into minecraft.

Is Bukkit the correct API to use? Does know of another API that will better meet my needs. I am not a java beginner.

Comment: I highly recommend you go to the Spigot forums to ask about the API, but I like how on Stack Overflow you'll get a high-quality answer most of the time. Or if it's not getting an answer on Spigot you can just put a bounty on it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Making the Custom Models

##### Background

You can do this absolutely. Since Minecraft version 1.9, Mojang introduced the ability to texture items based on their durability. What so exciting about this is it allows for virtually infinite custom models that don't replace existing ones! Yes, even if you go in survival and damage it so the exact durability you set the custom model at, it will still be seperate. This is because you can set the item to not be damaged, but still have a certain durability value. How sneaky! **The only problem is if you're developing for 1.8 (usually for a 1.8-latest server) then you can use any of this.**

How this works is, for example, a diamond hoe has a max durability of 1561. This means you can have 1560 different custom models by just using the diamond hoe! It's 1560 and not 1561 because 1561/1561 would be full durability or just a normal diamond hoe.

##### Create a basic resource pack

So, I'll start with Blockbench. To export your model, it's `File` -> `Export` -> `Export Block/Item Model`. That will export it as Json file. When you export the model don't name the item `diamond_hoe` or whatever item you'll be using under `model id`. Name it actually what it's going to be called. I'll show you why in this next step. You could even add a whole 'nother namespace if you wanted, but we'll just stick to the `Minecraft` namespace. To export the texture, right click it and press `Save As`.

We'll make a basic resource pack. Call the resource pack folder whatever you want. Put the Json in `<your resource pack folder>` -> `assets` -> `minecraft` -> `models` -> `item`. Put the texture in `<your resource pack folder>` -> `assets` -> `minecraft` -> `textures` -> `item`. In the resource pack folder you must also have a pack.mcmeta file and a pack.png file. You're most likely already familiar with this.

##### Custom model magic

After you have made a basic resource pack, it's time to create the model for diamond hoe, which will point to your model. This is why you named it the actual item in the previous step. The `diamond_hoe.json` should look something like this:

```
{
    "parent": "item/handheld",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/diamond_hoe"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {"predicate": {"damage": 0}, "model": "item/diamond_hoe"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.000640614990391}, "model": "item/your_custom_item" },
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 1}, "model": "item/diamond_hoe"}
    ]
}
```

The `predicate` modifier is what tells the game when a different model should be shown. [This tool](https://geenium.github.io/damage-value-generator/) can generate the Json for you. The damage value is whatever damage you want it to use over the total durability (e.g. one durability would be 1/1561 which equals 0.000640614990391).

After that your layout with just one custom item should look something like this:

```
.
└── resource pack folder/
    ├── assets/
    │   └── minecraft/
    │       ├── models/
    │       │   └── item/
    │       │       ├── diamond_hoe.json
    │       │       └── your_custom_item.json
    │       └── textures/
    │           └── item/
    │               └── your_custom_item.png
    ├── pack.mcmeta
    └── pack.png
```

Again, there's different ways you could lay it out. You could have your custom stuff in another namespace. This is just how I'm doing it though.

To add multiple items (for example three more items), modify your `diamond_hoe.json` to look like this:

```
{
    "parent": "item/handheld",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "item/diamond_hoe"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {"predicate": {"damage": 0}, "model": "item/diamond_hoe"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.000640614990391}, "model": "item/your_custom_item"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.001281229980782}, "model": "item/your_custom_item2"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.001921844971172}, "model": "item/your_custom_item3"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.002562459961563}, "model": "item/your_custom_item4"},
        {"predicate": {"damaged": 1}, "model": "item/diamond_hoe"}
    ]
}
```

## Bukkit/Spigot Plugin

Now, after all that. It's time to use the API. Yes, the Bukkit API is what you need. The Spigot API includes the Bukkit API, so you should be using the Spigot API. If you aren't already using it, change to that. No one uses the Bukkit server itself anymore. I'm assuming you're running a Spigot/Paper server. I will assume you are using the latest version 1.20.4 also.

You sound like you're new to Spigot plugins, so we'll make a plugin from scratch. Here is the basic layout of a Spigot plugin. You should already be familiar with the basic layout of a Java project, but here is what this project should end up looking like:

```
.
├── src
├── pom.xml/build.gradle
└── other_build_junk/
    └── main/
        ├── java/
        │   └── your_website_ending/me/
        │       └── your_company_or_name/
        │           └── yourplugin/
        │               ├── commands/
        │               │   └── GiveItem.java
        │               └── YourPlugin.java <- Main class
        └── resources/
            └── plugin.yml
```

Use your favorite Java IDE (it better be IntelliJ not Eclipse or anything else) to make a Java project, but if you have IntelliJ just install the `Minecraft Development` plugin and make a Minecraft project. It creates the `plugin.yml` and the build scripts for you. You can use whichever build system you want. I like Gradle, but I'll show you what the dependencies should look like for both.

Gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "spigotmc-repo"
        url = "https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Maven:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now, your main class should look like this:

```
public final class YourPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Register our "giveitem" command
        getCommand("giveitem").setExecutor(new GiveItem());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

Notice how it extends `JavaPlugin`. That is how it becomes a plugin. The `onEnable` and `onDisable` methods run every time the server is started or stopped. This line of code in the `onEnable` assigns our command `Giveitem`, to it's executor, the `GiveItem` class. It will be the command that gives us our custom item. Create the commands folder if you haven't already. Then, the `GiveItem` class. Which will end up looking like this:

```
public class GiveItem implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender commandSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {

        if (commandSender instanceof Player player) {
            
            // Create a diamond hoe that will become our item
            ItemStack customItem = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_HOE);
            // Item meta allows for modifying its data
            Damageable itemMeta = (Damageable) customItem.getItemMeta();
            // Set damage to 1 or like how we did in the json except the actual number
            // Why can't they do it this way in the json?
            itemMeta.setDamage(1);
            // Make it always stay the same durability
            itemMeta.setUnbreakable(true);
            // Use the following line to remove the extra lore we don't need
            itemMeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES, ItemFlag.HIDE_UNBREAKABLE);
            // Name it whatever you want
            itemMeta.setDisplayName("My Custom Item");
            customItem.setItemMeta(itemMeta);
            // Add item to player's inventory
            player.getInventory().addItem(customItem);
            
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you're wondering why we can't just use `give`, that would override the game's built-in `/give` command and we don't want to do that. Keep in mind you can get your item any way you like whether it's from a command, minigame, or a gui shop. We just want to get your item. That's why we're starting out with this basic command. That is what is so cool about the Spigot API though. You can build your Minecraft dreams. *Almost* anything you can imagine.

Anyways, your plugin.yml should look like this:

```
name: YourPlugin
version: '${version}' # Should be '${project.version}' for Maven
main: me.myname.yourplugin.YourPlugin
api-version: '1.20'
commands:
  giveitem:
    description:
      Give a custom item
```

This is what makes your plugin official. It also tells the server any commands that should be created for this plugin.

## Time to Test!

Finally, build your plugin (should already be ready in IntelliJ). If you're using something else use `package` command for Maven and `build` command for Gradle. Put the plugin into your server `plugin` folder. It should be in the `target` folder for Maven and the `build/libs` folder for Gradle.

Make sure your resource pack is in the right place. Launch Minecraft and enable your resource pack. Then, start up your server and once logged in, run the `giveitem` command we created with `/giveitem` and you should have your custom item!

Remember, you could make thousands, probably tens of thousands of custom items without replacing existing items. Also starting with version 1.14 they introduced the `custom_model_data` modifier which allows for many many more models. Although who's going to be making that many models!

Some of this I originally got from [this guide](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/custom-item-models-in-1-9-and-up/). It's slightly outdated now, but if you know the latest API, it works. Yikes, some of it's incorrect though. Maybe I should fix it...

Comment: Thank you so much for your very thorough investigation of this problem. On the java / server-side everything works, I can execute the "giveitem" command and indeed a diamond hoe is given. I am fighting with a weird problem with the resource packs, when I add my resource pack from the options screen, minecraft always moans "made for an older version of minecraft", regardless of pack format 18 or 19. Also the textures directory is a bit different than I expected from your posts, I have several textures in png format is this correct?

Comment: One very last question, my end goal is to make a craftable javelin. So I guess I could model it with the Trident to get throwing behavior. A javelin would be a less overpowered Trident but could be made with things found in lying about. But how would I go about getting the logic so that the user can craft it?

Comment: @dasPing As for the `made for an older version of Minecraft` it literally does not matter. As long as the files are in the correct layout and the models are made for 1.9+, it will work regardless of the warning. If you want to make it go away, what version are you using? 1.20.4? If so, the latest pack format is 22. You would have to make a data pack in addition to your resource pack to make your Javalin craftable. What's different about the directory? You should only have one texture png

Comment: I'll edit this answer to include some more things. I also shouldn't be giving you a normal diamond_hoe with the command, but your custom item

Comment: @dasPing Yes, model it with the trident so you can get that behavior. Using the diamond hoe is just an example. Made with things lying about... Like items floating on the ground or items you have to get from the world? How exactly do you plan to achieve that?

Comment: Actually don't use the trident as the model. You can't. Mojang made it that way. I'm writing some more code so we can throw the diamond hoe instead!

Comment: By using pack format 22 I get the warning away, lovely, but the texture is still being problematic. In my javelin.json which in your example is your_custom_item.json, I refer to the texture as follows "textures": {"layer0": item/javelin"} or "textures": {"0": item/javelin"} and in the textures directory I have a corresponding javelin.png but I only ever get the default texture. I will keep an eye out for you throwing logic, looking forward to it